# Fiddle me Thumbs

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom jsFiddle for StackOverflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49728/custom-jsfiddle-for-stackoverflow)

I've come across many posts on StackOverflow dealing with HTML, JavaScript, and/or CSS that show an example using [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). Even I tend to use the service for my own examples often. Which is why I'm proposing that the ability to embed jsFiddle into Stackoverflow posts become a possibility at the core.

Of course any other popular or most often used service that allows embedding would most likely benefit from the idea as well such as [wonderfl](http://wonderfl.net/) or [gist](https://gist.github.com/).

**Possible ways of handling this:**

- Embed the item when a link to a service is found
- `http://jsfiddle.net/mPb87/` --> 
  `<iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/mPb87/embedded/"></iframe>`
- Use a custom tag
- `[fiddle]mPb87[/fiddle]` --> 
  `<iframe src="http://jsfiddle.net/mPb87/embedded/"></iframe>`

Any thoughts on this?

---

<sup>Related content: [Custom jsFiddle for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49728/custom-jsfiddle-for-stackoverflow/63982#63982)</sup>