# Fiddel-style sandbox

Tags: feature-request, code-block, jsfiddle, code-examples

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom jsFiddle for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49728/custom-jsfiddle-for-stack-overflow)

I've noticed that more and more questions use [fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate their problem, and more and more answers have links to a fiddel as well.

This is great, cause it's

- Making it **easier for the asker to explain** him/herself
- **Saving time** for people who want to test the problem, and by that
- Increasing the chance for a **fast, high-quality answer**

But since not everybody is familiar with fiddel, and since sometimes people can't be bothered to use it, **all of these great advantages are not fully fulfilled**.

However, if you could, when asking or answering an answer, add a fiddel-like sandbox that demonstrates your code, **the overall quality of questions/answers might get much higher**.

It might also cause some improvement in the field of noobs' questions/answers, since if sharing the code becomes a norm, there will be no need for the infamous 'and where is your code?' comment, or solutions that obviously don't work.