# Did Stack Exchange make jsFiddle?

Tags: discussion, jsfiddle

I've been wondering whether Stack Exchange created jsFiddle, since users on Stack Exchange encourage people to use jsFiddle so much. Is that the case?

There is even a tag named [jsfiddle](/questions/tagged/jsfiddle) though I expect this was made by one of the people here.

Comment: How exactly do we encourage people to use jsFiddle?

Comment: jsfiddle is made by [zalun](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50024/176320) not stackoverflow

Comment: It is encouraged because all the time people ask if the owner of a question can make a fiddle

Comment: That might be encouraged @OllieCole, only if it's not in isolation. Posts should not fully rely on the jsFiddle or become irrelevant without them. To that effect, only including a jsFiddle is no longer allowed.

Comment: I know that you have to have code

Comment: Stack Overflow is encouraging people to try themselves before asking, and jsfiddle is a great tool for this purpose. However, those people still have to also post all the relevant code in their questions.

Comment: Users are encouraging, Stack Overflow is not... simple :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, jsFiddle was not made by Stack Exchange. If you go to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and click on "Legal, Credits and Links", you'll see that it is

> Created and maintained by [Piotr](http://webdev.zalewa.info/) and [Oskar](https://twitter.com/oskar).

And as it turns out, Piotr is also [a user on the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/50024/176320).

Another bit of "evidence" is the complete absence of any Stack Exchange footers or links on the site.

And while we do admittedly like the site and the tools it provides, [posting only a link to jsFiddle has been blocked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code). As you know, posts should not fully rely on the presence of a jsFiddle. A post has to be self-contained, perhaps with an additional jsFiddle for demonstration purposes.

Comment: -1 Too many glasses :)

Comment: I am not @cody's sockpuppet! Nope, not at all. Nothing to see here.... *shifty eyes* ... ah, that's not what you said.